# Where do I put my code in rails web app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Where is the correct place to put the following logic within a rails web app?

From a rake task or controller (I haven't decided yet), I want to generate and save into the database a load of a particular model. This generation logic will be quite complex and I wanted it unit testable. Given all this, it feels like rails wants me to put this code into the model class that is of the type my code is generating but that feels weird as it is very use case specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Given all this, it feels like rails wants me to put this code into the model class that is of the type my code is generating but that feels weird as it is very use case specific.

That sounds like a good reason to use a service object. That would typically be organized in lib/. E.g.

```
class MyLoadObjectService
  def load(params)
    # a bunch of logic to munge params into attribs
    MyLoadModel.create attribs
  end
end
```

Then call it in your controller:

```
def my_action
  MyLoadObjectService.new.load(params)
end
```

Comment: This sounds like a reasonable approach, I'd up-vote if I could. I find it interesting that rails doesn't seem to include any form of service layer in their conventions. Do you know if there is a rails way of doing this kind of thing for the sake of comparison?

Comment: @Matt Serivice Oriented Architecture is common in Rails. Just google it to find all kinds of examples, [for example](http://stevelorek.com/service-objects.html). It isn't a Rails-specific pattern, but doesn't need to be in order to be just as useful with Rails.